# Origin of the expression "being cagey about something"

Tags: etymology, expressions

What is the origin of the expression "being cagey about something"? Does it have anything to do with "being in a cage", not letting someone out of a cage? I googled for it but didn't get much:

> cagey
>   "evasive, reticent," 1909, U.S. colloquial, of unknown origin.
>   Online Etymology Dictionary, © 2010 Douglas Harper

Comment: Could this possibly be more to do with having "caged" emotions? I.e. not sharing your feelings with someone. Personally, I wouldn't compare the behaviour of a caged animal to someone who was acting cagey. I would think of a caged animal as acting volatile and not apprehensive or evasive as the adjective _cagey_ would suggest.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Summary: *Cagey* may have originated in boxing in 1890s America, and used in a more familiar way the following decade.

---

### Caged animals' behaviour

Owen Lattimore's [1990](http://books.google.fi/books?id=XCJ3AAAAMAAJ&q=%22cagey%22+slang&dq=%22cagey%22+slang&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bqdkT87TIebU4QSq8fmQCA&redir_esc=y) *China memoirs* suggests:

> "Cagey is American slang originated in the behavior of animals in a cage."

This is plausible; a caged animal can be wary, cautious and careful.

---

### Dictionary review

After checking 33 dictionary definitions listed by [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=cagey&ls=a&loc=2osdf), most say origin unknown and/or c. 1910 America, including [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cagey), but claims "First Known Use: circa 1893".

However, [Dictionary.com Unabridged](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cagey?r=66) ("Based on the Random House Dictionary") defines it as:

> cautious, wary, or shrewd: *a cagey reply to the probing question.*

And also gives an earlier date range and explicitly gives the root as *cage*:

> ***Origin:***
> 1890–95, *Americanism* ; cage  + -y

Additionally, a [1950](http://books.google.fi/books?ei=LjRqT6TaAsrFtAbahZyqAg&id=fMDyXHvPJqIC&dq=cagey%20slang&q=cagey%20#search_anchor) *Slang To-day and Yesterday* by Eric Partridge says:

> **Cagey.** Cautious in giving confidence (-1900).

---

### Cagey boxers in 1890s America

Here's some possible early uses.

From *[The Weekly Herald](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=newssearch&cd=39&ved=0CG8QqQIwEjgU&url=http://news.google.com/newspapers?id=-0NeAAAAIBAJ&sjid=s2ANAAAAIBAJ&pg=6344,3490184&dq=cagey%2b%257C%2bcagy&hl=en&ei=aABlT67uN63T4QS11JXyBw&usg=AFQjCNFVTT-CObVlQE88F4XCdpMXTnuV5g)*, August 21, 1892, in a preview of a night of boxing entitled "Scene And Personnel Of the Great Fights at New Orleans, September 5, 6, and 7.", written by Mike Donovan. The last fight of the night:

> So while Skelly is a good man and clever enough, he has yet to get a good bit of professional experience before e can be expected to best Dixon. That man is bigboned, muscular, sinewy, nervy, **"cagey;"** his eye, his head and his hands work to gether all the lime. His body blows are terrors, and I must say that Skelly, fine as he looks, wil have a hard time of it against the clever Boston boy.

Later that year, *cagey* again shows up in a boxing context. *[The Morning Herald](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=newssearch&cd=36&ved=0CGYQqQIwDzgU&url=http://news.google.com/newspapers?id=zURCAAAAIBAJ&sjid=MrkMAAAAIBAJ&pg=2935,2228163&dq=cagey%2b%257C%2bcagy&hl=en&ei=aABlT67uN63T4QS11JXyBw&usg=AFQjCNGI7lAwUjcgOWlegQxnuI2vkdKGmg)* of November 1, 1892 has report on "Choynski The Victor: He Knocks Godfrey Out in Fifteen Rounds" at Coney Island on 31st October:

> Round Eleven— From the **cagey** manner in which this round was there was every indication that it would prove a long battle. Both men had their left eyes almost closed, but with this exception they looked as though they could last for a week. All the punching that was done was light with the exception of a few stomach punches.

Next, the variant *cagy* shows up in another boxing report, published in both the *[Warsaw Daily Times](https://www.google.com/url?url=http://news.google.com/newspapers?id=qohHAAAAIBAJ&sjid=knwMAAAAIBAJ&pg=4568,2167677&dq=cagey%2b%257C%2bcagy&hl=en&rct=j&sa=X&ei=aABlT67uN63T4QS11JXyBw&ved=0CF4Q-AsoADANOBQ&q=cagey%20OR%20cagy&usg=AFQjCNF-lFZ67sx-thDqckx1wuq3Zx56KA)* and *[Aurora Daily Express](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=newssearch&cd=34&ved=0CF0QqQIwDTgU&url=http://news.google.com/newspapers?id=8qIoAAAAIBAJ&sjid=CQYGAAAAIBAJ&pg=3433,5057092&dq=cagey%2b%257C%2bcagy&hl=en&ei=aABlT67uN63T4QS11JXyBw&usg=AFQjCNGaiXIlWeQGMBkSv26IAUGD-GVzMg)* (and probably the *[Atlanta Constitution](http://pqasb.pqarchiver.com/ajc_historic/access/530879942.html?FMT=ABS&FMTS=ABS:AI&type=historic&date=Mar%2009,%201893&author=&pub=The%20Atlanta%20Constitution%20%281881-2001%29&desc=STARS%20AND%20STRIPES&pqatl=google)*) of March 9, 1893:

> Round 1.-Both men came to the scratch with a jauntiness which showed their seeming lack of care. They commenced work in a very **cagy** manner until Fitzsimmons finally led with the left and fell short of his mark, Hall's left on the counter barely touching his face.

---

### 1900s American newspapers

The following decade we can find more familiar uses of the term. I've noted which of these are pay-per-view as I've not paid to verify the OCR is correct.

Pay-Per-View - *The Sun* - Apr 6, 1900

> There is something gallant, says. the Brooklyn Eagle, even if amateur, in the Admiral's candid, brief, albeit somewhat cagy. announcement.

A story on a "Magical Wine Cask‎" in the *Lawrence Daily World* of Oct 2, 1901 uses *cagey* twice to mean *careful*:

> The labels read "Assmannshauser." There was not a suggestion anywhere of "Oberingelheimer." The dealer had remarked with a sly wink: "I am very **cagey** on wines; nobody can beat me in the selection". But the box was nailed up, and a note informed the seller that a mistake has been made. Hearing nothing in reply the purchaser called for an explanation, says the New York Press.
>
> "So they sent you Assmannshauser instead Oberingelheimer, did they?" said the **cagey**  man."Did you taste it? No? If you had tasted it you would have seen at once it was Oberingelheimer. My man made a mistake in pasting the wrong labels. I will send for the case and have the labels changed, if you like, but it will make no difference in the taste of the wine, because A and O are drawn from the same cask. These are the only two brands of red Rhine wines, and only the shrewdest expert can tell which is which."

Pay-Per-View - *Detroit Free Press* - Jul 6, 1902:

> Mercer pitched his usual **cagey** game, and the fourth, mentioned above, was the only one in which more than one hit was registered against him.

Pay-Per-View - *Detroit Free Press* - Aug 28, 1909:

> Pltle got **cagey** when askedi where he had taken the single load of fttrnititre and things. and decided not to tell. except that he had driven them to ...

The *[Evening Sentinel](http://news.google.com/newspapers?id=XQtXAAAAIBAJ&sjid=_UINAAAAIBAJ&pg=1686,4816293&dq=cagey&hl=en)* of Aug 19, 1910, in an article about former president Theodore Roosevelt titled "The Colonel Is Saying Nothing. Refuses To Discuss Breach Between Himself and Taft":

> In case the old guard goes to Saratoga and tries to undo what it has already done, which is mighty doubtful, they might realize that with New York lost the colonel [Roosevelt] would be a good man to captain the sinking ship and go down with it. The colonel is pretty **"cagey"** when It comes to matters of this sort. For that reason he believes that he had bolter wait and make his onslaught of a ...

---

### 1900s American serial dime novels

*Cagey* is used in the modern sense in the New York nickel weekly *Secret Service: Old and Young King Brady, Detectives*.

*The Bradys and Dr. Hop Low; or, The Deepest Mott Street Mystery* of January 4, [1907](http://books.google.fi/books?id=7KH6IEe_U4wC&pg=PA6&dq=cagey&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RP1pT4CEIePc4QS6983-CA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=cagey&f=true) by [A New-York City Detective](http://www.thrillingdetective.com/more_eyes/old_king_brady.html):

> "Strange."
> "Very. The place seems to he hoodooed."
> "Did you ever ask Hop Foon about it?"
> "Yes."
> "What does he say?"
> "He can give no reason."
> "**Or will not. These Chinese are very cagey.**"
> "Don't I know it! I ought to. I’ve been dealing with them for the last ten years."

The next year: *The Bradys and Little Chin-Chin; or, Exposing an Opium Gang* of January 31, [1908](http://books.google.fi/books?id=-3IPR3nIhlUC&pg=PA22&dq=cagey&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RP1pT4CEIePc4QS6983-CA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=cagey&f=false):

> “Shall you arrest them?” demanded Charley.
>
> “Not yet,” replied Old King Brady. “Of course, they must have heard of the notice on the bulletin, but they are **too cagey to show their hands**. No doubt they backed this man Ramage up with money to embark in the jewelry importing business. We will wait a bit. and see what move they make."

---

### Footnote: 19th century Scottish *cheerful*

There's an earlier Scottish term *cagey* which may be unrelated, and means cheerful or joyful.

From the addenda of *Two ancient Scottish poems: the Gaberlunzie-man, and Christ's Kirk on the Green* by James V (King of Scotland), John Callander of [1782](http://books.google.fi/books?id=n3asZysbisAC&pg=PA84&dq=cagey%20OR%20cagy&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NxRlT6yZH6qG4gTniJmOCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=cagey%20OR%20cagy&f=false):

> Ver. 8. Cadgily] The word *cadge* is probably derived from the Sclavonian *chodge*, to trudge on foot; whence, too, our so *fentgy*[?], a little wench, who does the dirty work in a farmer's kitchen. The word *cadgy*, in the present case, should, I think, be written ***cagy***, or ***cagie***, which would agree better with the pronounciation [*sic*]. It imports *merry, chearful, jovial*, and is, I believe, an abbreviation of the old French word *cagedler*, the same with *cajoler*, to cajole, slatter, cox.

There's also another note about *Cadgily* which links it to *cadgers* who carry goods for sale in *cages*, also called *creels*, "who use to sing, in order to beguile the tediousness of the way. From primitive *ca, cad, cap*, anything made for *containing*, possibly from Gaelic *cadhla*.

This Scottish word is used in *Blackwood's Edinburgh magazine*: Volume 9 of [1821](http://books.google.fi/books?id=Fk65TeMYKGEC&pg=PA258&dq=cagey%20OR%20cagy&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ihdlT-mNCKaD4gTq6cHZBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=cagey%20OR%20cagy&f=false):

> It was such an early hour that the steward, not counting on any body wanting to breakfast till they would reach Greenock, had made no provision of provender; so that when I went to him, as **cagy** as a pyet [magpie] picking at a worm, to inquire when the eggs would be boiled, judge of my mortification to hear that there was to be no breakfasting that morning; which disappointment, with the natural vapours of the river's tide, caused me to remember the judicious observe of Mrs M'Leckit, that there was a danger in going on the water with an empty stomach. However I had put some ginge-bread nuts in my pocket, and by the use of them the wind was keepit off my heart, and I suffered less from the effect than might have been expected.

And in [1821](http://books.google.fi/books?id=KNsv4NudEAoC&pg=PA104&dq=cagey%20OR%20cagy&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ihdlT-mNCKaD4gTq6cHZBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=cagey%20OR%20cagy&f=false)'s *Annals of the parish: or, the chronicle of Dalmailing* by John Galt:

> ... bed at Kilmarnock, where they stopped that night ; but when they came back to the lady's in the morning, she was as **cagey** and meikle taken up with them, as if they had gotten her full consent and privilege to marry from the first.

*[Meikle](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meikle)* is a variant of *[mickle](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mickle)*: chiefly Scottish meaning *great, much*.

And more from John Galt, [1834](http://books.google.fi/books?id=_wA6AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA76&dq=cagey%20OR%20cagy&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kxtlT-a9PMn-4QS-77iQCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=cagey%20OR%20cagy&f=false)'s *The literary life, and miscellanies: in three volumes: Volume 3*, has a cheerful meaning of *cagy*:

> She just had some milk in a saucer, and, rolling up a bit of rag, she dipped it in, held it to the bairn's mouth, and he was as **cagy** about it as if it had been a pap of the motherly gender.

And again in the same volume:

> But I had little though of that them, for it was a blithe [joyous] morning, with the dew on the grass, and the laverock in the lift, and I was as **cagy** with the thought of going to do for myself as if my een were haill, and I a skipping mawkin [hare/simpleton].

---

### Footnote continued: early 20th century American sexual desire

A snippet from [1917](http://books.google.fi/books?id=c1NFAQAAIAAJ&q=cagey%20slang&dq=cagey%20slang&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6wZqT8HsPKyk4ASXsv34CA&redir_esc=y)'s *Dialect notes, Volume 4* by the American Dialect Society says:

> **cagey, cajy** *(k édzi), adj.* Having strong sexual desire ; esp. of a male. “The stallion is quite *cajy* after seeing a mare go by.”

And a snippet from their [1928](http://books.google.fi/books?ei=FjdqT83rFIfe4QS6xbiSCQ&id=axwOAAAAIAAJ&dq=cagey%20dialect&q=cagey%20#search_anchor) *Dialect notes, Volume 6* says:

> “*Cagey* and *horny* are the ordinary words for sensual, and are never used in polite company.

This has roots from the Scottish *cagey*, joyful, as Michael Montgomery [2006](http://books.google.fi/books?id=I957OegamHMC&pg=PA34&dq=cagey&hl=en&sa=X&ei=njVqT7ytC4Pysgbc9fiVAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=cagey&f=true)'s *From Ulster to America: the Scotch-Irish heritage of American English* explains:

> **cadgy, cagey, caigey, caigy** *adj* Spirited, sportive (in the US also amorous, sexually aroused), [origin uncertain; OED *cadgy* adj 1 'sexually excited' cl724—>, Scottish and northern dialect, 2 ‘cheerful, merry, glad, 1725->; SND *cadgy* ‘cheerful, in good spirits; dotingly amorous; eagerly willing’; DARE *cadgy* adj ‘lively, excited, spry; especially of stallions: sexually aroused’ chiefly South Midland]
>
> ULST:
> **1880** Patterson *Antrim/Down Glossary* 16 *caigey* = in very good spirits, lively, wanton, eager.
> **c1910** Byers *Glossary, cagey* = in good spirits, gay, cheerful, sportive: ‘He’s a cagey boy’.
> **1953** Traynor *Donegal Glossary* 42 *cadgy* = gay, cheerful, in good spirits.
> **2000** Fenton *Hamley Tongue* 31 *caigy* = full of sexual desire.
> U.S.:
> **1917** Kephart *Word-list* 409 *caigy* = full of sexual desire.
> **1955** Parris *Roaming Mts* 177 The dogs are cagey. They are born to taunt rather than fight.
> **1993** Walker *Life History* 30 [A powder was] used to make the animals ‘cagey’ and reproduce.

Comment: I really thought I'd found the "first use to end all first uses", with this 1816 reference to a [smooth and sometimes shining paste, which is so gratifying to the cagey eye of the antiquary](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22cagey+eye+of+the+antiquary%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Sadly, it turns out to be an OCR misreading of **eager**, but it did seem to read perfectly well to me in the sense of *watchful, careful*...

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes, the OCR really must be carefully verified, which is why I noted the Pay-Per-Views: at least *Mercer pitched his usual cagey game* could really be *easy game*. (I confirmed all the non-PPVs.)

Comment: I wonder if Google would be interested in bankrolling SO/ELU to develop a "bolt-on" to our site making it easy for us to notify them of obvious howlers/suspect readings. Any info thus gained would presumably never get lost again, and over time could significantly increase the value of their index database.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Could you explain what you mean by that? I don't understand that first sentence. "Howlers/suspect readings"? What is that? and what is SO/ELU?

Comment: @Aerovistae: ELU is **us**, StackOverflow is the parent site. I mean we can see OCR misreadings, and if Google paid SO the costs of implementing an interface so we could easily flag up errors, that would increase the accuracy/value of their Books indexes, so they might want to do that

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Google already has such a bolt-on: click [About this book](http://books.google.fi/books?id=G1BBAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22cagey+eye+of+the+antiquary%22&source=gbs_navlinks_s) on the left, then scroll down and [Report an issue](http://support.google.com/books/bin/answer.py?hl=en&v=G1BBAAAAYAAJ&is=atb&source=gbs_navlinks_s&answer=180577&dq=%22cagey+eye+of+the+antiquary%22&url=http:%2F%2Fbooks.google.fi%2Fbooks%3Fid%3DG1BBAAAAYAAJ) then select "An error in the display of book pages" and " An error with typos/OCR errors in the book's text".

Comment: @Hugo: ty for that. I suppose I'd better report the *eager/cagey* misreading - if it weren't for this particular question on ELU, who would notice anything odd about the OCR version?

Answer (score 3):

According to the OED, colloquial and orginally from the US. First recorded use in 1909, etymology unknown.

Comment: Merriam Webster says 'first recorded use c1893', but gives no details.

Comment: @TimLymington: The two no doubt have different criteria for inclusion.

Comment: [John Borthwick Gilchrist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Gilchrist_(surgeon)), writes in 1815 of being [exposed...to many severe mortifications, painful remonstrances, bitter reflections, and a number of stale sarcasms and gibes, such as getting Cagey in my old age](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qm1S1JzM2_QC&pg=PA92&dq=%22such+as+getting+Cagey+in+my+old+age%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1vpdT47RIs7L8QPvk-TNCw&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22such%20as%20getting%20Cagey%20in%20my%20old%20age%22&f=false). It looks pretty much like the modern sense to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You may want to let the editors of the OED know. They say 'etymology unknown', but it's surely something based on being confined in a cage, don't you think?

Comment: N-Grams certainly suggests it only came into popular usage during the early stages of the 20th century. http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cagey&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: Since we're guessing, couldn't it be a mishearing/misunderstanding of *chary*?

Comment: There's also this oft-quoted (1841?) [cagey and meikle](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cagey+and+meikle%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which the third citation helpfully paraphrases as *"sportive and greatly"*. I see no great stretch from *sportive, playful* to *"unforthcoming"*. We often say things like *"Don't play games with me"* when we mean *"Stop being evasive"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think Gilchrist was using the word "Cagey" in the modern sense. The word is capitalized and italicized, so it seems to reference a particular place. Later in the sentence he speaks of living in *Burdy House* which is a place of captivity/purgatory. Gilchrist is Scottish. I think it's quite likely he was referring to Macpherson of Cluny, who during the Jacobite uprising of 1745 hid in a cave at Ben Alder (his "cage") for 8 years. Perhaps the modern meaning "evasive" **is** ultimately related to this "go into hiding" sense used by Scottish immigrants to the USA…

Comment: I did a bit more research on possible scottish origins of "cagey" and found [this](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/getent4.php?plen=4290&startset=5039196&query=CADGY&fhit=cagy&dregion=form&dtext=snd#fhit) which explains *cagey and [meikle](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/getent4.php?plen=7634&startset=3264164&query=MUCKLE&fhit=meikle&dregion=entry&dtext=sndn#fhit)* but doesn't have anything to do with evasiveness or going into hiding.

Comment: @ghoppe: I'm wasn't saying either the Gilchrist *"cagey in my old age"* or the (John Galt?) *"cagey and meikle"* directly equate to the modern meaning - just that neither seem a huge stretch, given how (particularly, idiomatic) meanings often morph considerably. They may be totally unconnected, but it wouldn't surprise me if either or both were part of a gradual shift. I doubt Gilchrist's capitalisation means much - he capitalised *"Banker"* and *"Starlings"* in the preceding paragraph, for example - just his style, typical of the age.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Both "Banker" and "Starlings" are used as proper nouns, referring to a particular archetypal person "the Banker" and his particular pet birds. (Also, it used to be common to capitalize a species name in English.) I maintain that "Cagey" is referring to a particular place (in this case, Cluny's Cage) — skimming through his writing it doesn't seem he capitalizes at random.

Comment: @FumbleFingers After reading the previous page of that Gilchrist reference, it occurs to me that he need not be referencing Cluny. I think it's pretty explicit what he's talking about, in context. He writes on page 91: “… my then projected *editorial lucubrations,* must long ere now have consigned me *to an iron cage,* not quite so convenient or agreeable for *its captive* starling, as the extensive *wire works* which cover the roof my house, are for their various tenants.”

Comment: @ghoppe: I don't feel that strongly about it. If you're sure of your position I don't feel I have to persuade you otherwise. But here's (also Scottish, from 1821) [as cagy as a pyet (magpie) picking at a worm](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lb0CAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA258&dq=cagy&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pHdeT-inHsWn0QWNwcyOBw&ved=0CFYQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=cagy&f=false), which could be as much "guarded, wary" as "sportive, playful".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I that that sense is clearly the scottish slang I linked above meaning "in good spirits, brisk, lively". A magpie with a worm is decidedly happy. :)

Comment: @ghoppe: We're just going round in circles. I said at the beginning that we often say things like "Don't play games with me" when we mean "Stop being evasive".

Answer (score 3):

As a quick line of thought:

'Cagey' coming from a 'caged' answer, coming from 'caged', or 'confined' / 'restricted'. From Cavea - the latin for subterranean cells.

Comment: +1: Similar to a *hedged answer/reply*, which is fairly standard usage.

Answer (score -2):

If you look at the definition of the Old French noun *cage*, it isn't hard to see the similarity in meaning between *cage* and our current word "cagey.

*cage* early 13c., from O.Fr. cage "cage, prison, retreat, hideout"

Comment: Why the down-vote?  This is a legitimate and relevant response.  Tough crowd here.